# Global Database Helper class

Tags: android

My requirement is to create a db helper class for android which will do all data base operations. but by passing a class to the db helper, it should create a table with the field names as columns.

In that way i should be able to use this for any class with any fields.
Post any of the links related to this or any hints for achieving this.
Response is appreciated.

Comment: Do not mix up the various functionality and just keep basic functionality under the db helper class like: creating the database if not exists, update the database, open the database. Rest of all the operations like insert, delete, update, get etc in their respective repository classes.

Comment: @jitainsharma : thats fyn.. but how can i create database table with fcolumn names as field names of the model class. i guess its somethng related to object mapping( i am not sure)

Comment: You can use OrmLite, or any other ORM framework, or just map by your own, while using any ORM, read carefully what they support, and your need is full filled or not.